# Decode yyyy-MM-dd date

Tags: swift, date, decode

I am trying to parse a "yyyy-MM-dd" date string but it always returns the date with hours.

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let date: Date
}
let string = """
        {"date": "2023-10-19"}
        """
let data = Data(string.utf8)
let foo: Foo = try parse(data: data)

let formatter = DateFormatter()      
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let swiftObject = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

Returns 2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

JSON: 
data: {
     date: 2023-10-19 
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. You're just looking at the debug output of viewing a `Date` instance. When you want to display the `Date` to the user, use a `DateFormatter` to display the date in whatever desired format you want.

Comment: thank U @HangarRash I just update the question

Comment: @EduardoOliveros `formatter` is not a valid `dateDecodingStrategy`. Please edit your question and post your real code

Comment: Don't forget to post your JSON string `data` and your method declaration (with your generic T declaration)

Comment: @LeoDabus 
/// Decode the `Date` as a string parsed by the given formatter.
        case formatted(DateFormatter)

Comment: @EduardoOliveros yes thats what I thought your code would look like. Anyway please edit your question and post an [mcve]

Comment: .formatted(formatter) formatter is a DateFormatter

Comment: Btw you should always set your date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" when using a fixed date format. You should also set your calendar as well when not parsing a timeless date string.

Comment: If you want to display the date without the time component, you would use a `DateFormatter` to convert the `Date` object back into a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two questions here:

1. How come when you print the `Date` object, you see hours, minutes and seconds, too?

   That is because when you `print` a `Date` object it always includes that information, in that format. If you want to display a `Date` object in your UI, though, you would use a separate UI-specific date formatter for that.
2. How come when you parse a JSON with the date of “2023-10-19” you ended up with a date of 2000-01-01?

   This must be a mistake introduced when composing the question, because there is no way you would have ended up with that date given that input.

   That having been said, you must set the `locale` of the formatter in case your user is using a device which is not using a Gregorian calendar. By default, we use the `en_US_POSIX` locale when encoding/decoding JSON, just to make sure we’re using a consistent format. See [TN1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). That is for Objective-C, but it outlines the locale concerns.

Thus, we end up with:

```swift
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let date: Date
}

func parse<T: Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> T {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
}

do {
    let string = """
        {"date": "2023-10-19"}
        """
    let data = Data(string.utf8)
    let foo: Foo = try parse(data: data)
    print(foo.date)                         // 2023-10-19 07:00:00 +0000; this is just the default description for the `Date` type
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium           // note, we generally avoid using `dateFormat` strings for date formatters for our UI, but rather `dateStyle`
    print(formatter.string(from: foo.date)) // Oct 19, 2023
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Great! thank U, and why we need to use en_US_POSIX?

Comment: In different calendars (notably non-Gregorian ones), the string “2023-10-19” will represent very different dates which can be hundreds of years different. So, as a matter of practice, we store dates in this posix format so that we store everything in a single, consistent, device-independent format. Now, when you use that second formatter (with the `dateStyle`, but not overriding the `locale`), this date will be shown in the UI in the user’s preferred calendar/format. So we show/capture `Date` objects in the user’s preferred format, but store it in this device-independent posix format.